# How can I embed a Python function that returns a string in C using cffi?

Tags: python, c, string, pypy, python-cffi

I'm trying to embed a Python function in C using PyPy and cffi. I'm following [this guide](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/embedding.html) from the PyPy documentation.

The problem is, all the examples I've found operate on ints, and my function takes a string and returns a string. I can't seem to figure out how to embed this function in C, as C doesn't seem to really have strings, rather making do with arrays of chars.

Here's what I've tried:

```
# interface.py

import cffi

ffi = cffi.FFI()
ffi.cdef('''
struct API {
    char (*generate_cool_page)(char url[]);
};
''')

...


@ffi.callback("char[] (char[])")
def generate_cool_page(url):
    # do some processing with BS4
    return str(soup)

def fill_api(ptr):
    global api 
    api = ffi.cast("struct API*", ptr)
    api.generate_cool_page = generate_cool_page
```

--

```
// c_tests.c

#include "PyPy.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct API {
    char (*generate_cool_page)(char url[]);
};

struct API api;   /* global var */

int initialize_api(void)
{
    static char source[] =
        "import sys; sys.path.insert(0, '.'); "
        "import interface; interface.fill_api(c_argument)";
    int res;

    rpython_startup_code();
    res = pypy_setup_home(NULL, 1);
    if (res) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting pypy home!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    res = pypy_execute_source_ptr(source, &api);
    if (res) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error calling pypy_execute_source_ptr!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    if (initialize_api() < 0)
        return 1;

    printf(api.generate_cool_page("https://example.com"));

    return 0;
}
```

When I run `gcc -I/opt/pypy3/include -Wno-write-strings c_tests.c -L/opt/pypy3/bin -lpypy3-c -g -o c_tests` and then run `./c_tests`, I get this error:

```
debug: OperationError:
debug:  operror-type: CDefError
debug:  operror-value: cannot render the type <char()(char *)>: it is a function type, not a pointer-to-function type
Error calling pypy_execute_source_ptr!
```

I don't have a ton of experience with C and I feel like I'm misrepresenting the string argument/return value. How do I do this properly?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that you should not be using pypy's deprecated interface to embedding; instead, see http://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/embedding.html.

The C language doesn't have "strings", but only arrays of chars.  In C, a function that wants to return a "string" is usually written
differently: it accepts as first argument a pointer to a pre-existing buffer (of type `char[]`), and as a second argument the length of that buffer; and when called, it fills the buffer.  This can be messy because you ideally need to handle buffer-too-small situations in the caller, e.g. allocate a bigger array and call the function again.

Alternatively, some functions give up and return a freshly `malloc()`-ed `char *`.  Then the caller must remember to `free()` it, otherwise a leak occurs.  I would recommend that approach in this case because guessing the maximum length of the string before the call might be difficult.

So, something like that.  Assuming you start with
http://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/embedding.html, change
`plugin.h` to contain::

```
// return type is "char *"
extern char *generate_cool_page(char url[]);
```

And change this bit of `plugin_build.py`::

```
ffibuilder.embedding_init_code("""
    from my_plugin import ffi, lib

    @ffi.def_extern()
    def generate_cool_page(url):
        url = ffi.string(url)
        # do some processing
        return lib.strdup(str(soup))   # calls malloc()
""")
ffibuilder.cdef("""
    #include <string.h>
    char *strdup(const char *);
""")
```

From the C code, you don't need `initialize_api()` at all in the
new embedding mode; instead, you just say `#include "plugin.h"`
and call the function directly::

```
char *data = generate_cool_page("https://example.com");
if (data == NULL) { handle_errors... }
printf("Got this: '%s'\n", data);
free(data);   // important!
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right documentation - I'll try this out!

Comment: are you sure I don't need `initialize_api()`? GCC is giving me `undefined reference to 'generate_cool_page'`. (I have included `plugin.h`)

Comment: Read very carefully how to compile, at the page I linked to.  There are two options for two different use cases.  It seems you're following neither of these options...

Comment: Oops, sorry. I was a bit tired and accidentally ignored part of the documentation. After removing `#include <string.h>` from the cdef call (it wouldn't compile with it, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-cffi/vDAw37NHRSg), building the plugin and figuring out how to use gcc, I have this error: `TypeError: initializer for ctype 'char *' must be a bytes or list or tuple, not str`. The line mentioned is the `return lib.strdup(str(soup))` statement.

Comment: Agh I really need to learn to actually read error messages. After converting the `str(soup)` to a `bytes` object it works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: how to access this generate_cool_page function  from c#

Comment: @Rawat: `def_extern` makes a function compiled as C code in a DLL.  You can call it from any language that can invoke C code, like C#.  Look up your language's own ffi (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110706/how-does-extern-work-in-c)

Comment: @ArminRigo ok i resolved this now, i have another problem now i want to send image, i have posted my code and problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63870021/cffi-export-python-code-to-dll-how-to-read-image-object-in-ffi-def-extern  please have a look